# How do you move one server to another server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

Is there a way you can move a server to another server? This includes all the progress, the loot you have, etc., because we started in a free server as a joke but now it is pretty big and it's lagging so we want to move that server to a high-quality server.

Comment: Are you using some kind of service or do you actually have access to the files?

Comment: I'm using a service i dont think i have access to the files maybe it provides it but idk

Comment: You should at least have an option to download a backup. So download the backup of one server, restore the world from backup on the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy. You just need to transfer the folder from the first server to another server. If you will switch ips by connecting to another internet then problems might occur like: the first ip not working, The second ip not being setten up. The port might wrong and all. But I am sure it's possible.

Note: I am not an expert in minecraft servers but i had a mc servers for my friend to connect to a private server.